# How do I remove these errors from my blog so as to get adsense approved?

Tags: wordpress, google-adsense, sitemap, blog

This is the question I asked on SO site earlier, but didn't get satisfactory replies. hoping to find a solution here..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136796/how-can-i-detect-and-correct-these-errors-on-my-blog/12136829#comment16235061_12136829

In web master tools, apart from the errors in the question link above, it is showing a site map error too as in the screenshot below:-

[image]

Need guidance please...thanks :)

Edit -1

EDIT 2

I had 2 SEO plugins on my blog and I would put meta description for each of my article in both plugins that are All in One SEO and Yoast's "Wordpress SEO". Now I removed all article's meta descriptions from "All in one SEO" the other day but STILL web master tool is showing duplicate meta tags and descriptions. Why??

Comment: What does this have to do with Adsense? Did Google tell you that this specific error is why you got rejected?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: My adsense application got rejected twice. The reason google gave was "Blog doesn't comply to Google's policies". I have been trying to understand what this general reason means on my own because Google guys won't reply. So I came across these errors and thought, these might be the reason for rejection. If not these, then what could it be?? I am writing ALL original useful content and its not a personal blog, its 6 months old. I am at a fail to understand what's wrong. What do you think Google won't approve? I really need help on this.

Comment: It definitely isn't a missing sitemap. If you have anything bordering on illegal/copyrighted that could be it. Or maybe you don't have enough content yet.

Comment: I always pass all my articles through Copyscape premium so no issues of duplicate content. Also, there are more than 100 articles on my blog now. Its 6 months old.

Answer (score 3):

### Sitemap

Sitemaps that you submit to Google are usually in XML format:
See http://www.sitemaps.org/ for details.

They often have a filename of the form: "Sitemap.xml"

And look something like this (source: http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>
      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
      <priority>0.8</priority>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

These are machine readable, not intended for end users. They simply inform Google about all the pages on your site.

However, Google is reporting that the sitemap you have submitted is in HTML format. Sitemaps for humans to read are usually in HTML.

### Duplicate Meta Descriptions

The cause for this is likely to be a conflict between your SEO plugins. So you need to remove one or both of these, or configure them so they don't output a meta description.

If you have already done this then it can take some time before Google recrawls your site and refreshes these reports. Google won't acknowledge your changes instantly.

As is suggested, the Meta Description should be unique for every page. And should be a short (but not too short) description of what is on that page, not your site as a whole.

### Site (Source Code) Analysis

I've just been to have a quick look at your site and you appear to have some fundamental errors in the source regarding duplicated meta tags. These need to be resolved.

You said you'd updated the plugins meta descriptions, however, this does not seem to have happened. You still have a conflict between the plugins. There are 3 lots of meta descriptions on the same page. Using [this page](http://www.valcun.com/stuff-9gaggers-hate/) as an example...

Near the top of your page you have the first group. The keywords meta tag is erroneously repeating the meta description.

```
<meta name="description" content="As a 9Gagger I know what 9Gaggers like or hate. So here I am, writing about some things that 9Gaggers hate. Did you know about this stuff?
 Read more" />
<meta name="keywords" content="As a 9Gagger I know what 9Gaggers like or hate. So here I am, writing about some things that 9Gaggers hate. Did you know about this stuff?
 Read more, Entertainment" />
```

Added by Yoast plugin:

```
<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast WordPress SEO plugin v1.2.7 - http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/ -->
<title>Stuff 9Gaggers Hate | Valcun</title>
<meta name="description" content="As a 9Gagger I know what 9Gaggers like or hate. So here I am, writing about some things that 9Gaggers hate. Did you know about this stuff?"/>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.valcun.com/stuff-9gaggers-hate/" />
<!-- / Yoast WordPress SEO plugin. -->
```

Added by All in One SEO:

```
<!-- All in One SEO Pack 1.6.14.6 by Michael Torbert of Semper Fi Web Designob_start_detected [-1,-1] -->
<meta name="description" content="As a 9Gagger I know what 9Gaggers like or hate. So here I am, writing about some things that 9Gaggers hate. Did you know about this stuff?" />
<meta name="keywords" content="9gag,memes,entertainment" />
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.valcun.com/stuff-9gaggers-hate/" />
<!-- /all in one seo pack -->
```

This line (near the very top of your source) should have a `"` after `follow`, not `'`. In fact you should probably remove this line and the Googlebot line altogether since "index,follow" are the default actions.

```
<meta name="Robots" content="Index,follow'/>
```

### Adsense Application Rejected

However, whilst the above coding issues are not going to help, they are probably not the main reasons why your Adsense application is being rejected. It is more likely to be related to the content of your site (quantity or subject matter) or the personal information you have provided in your application.

Comment: Now how do I fix it? I don't know how to make an XML file.

Comment: The link I give in my answer tells you everything you need to know about XML sitemaps. An XML file is simply an ordinary text file with HTML-like tags and attributes (I'll update my answer with an example). HOWEVER, you appear to be using Wordpress. In Wordpress you are more likely to be using a plugin that generates the XML sitemap for you.

Comment: I am already using Google XML sitemap named plugin and this is the file it generates on regular basis..I just checked..http://www.valcun.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: This is the latest msg by that plugin...Your sitemap was last built on August 28, 2012 6:16 am.

Comment: That's good, but that does not seem to be the file that Google is complaining about, it mentions "/site-map/" in the URL. It is possible to submit multiple sitemaps. Maybe this HTML file has been submitted in error and simply needs to be removed in Google Webmaster Tools?

Comment: I just tried something in web master tools..I added site map again and submitted this address valcun.com/sitemap.xml and google accepted it. It is now showing as 'Pending'. So, I guess sitemap is sorted but what about duplicate metas? How do I get rid of those errors about duplicates?

Comment: I've updated my answer about duplicate meta tags, having looked at the source code of your page.

Comment: Can you please tell me which php file in wordpress I need to edit this line? <meta name="Robots" content="Index,follow'/>

Comment: Since it's a structural markup issue I would guess it's in one of your templates? If in doubt, try searching your files for `<meta`?